# rdiff-backup on WindowsOS: cannot get "--exclude C:/target/stuff" to work

Tags: cygwin, backup, rdiff-backup

I am working on backing up a number of local and non-local files to my Windows machine. I am familiar with rdiff-backup from other Linux boxes that I use. I have installed rdiff-backup using instructions etc from here, 
http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/index.html

I have rdiff-backup installed and it appears to be working "almost" fine. The problem is that I have a directory that I want to exclude. On a linux OS I could just do,

```
rdiff-backup --exclude C:/target/stuff C:/ D:/backup
```

However this does not work on a WindowsOS machine. Using the suggested formatting posted here:

http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/Windows-README.txt

I have tried the following,

```
rdiff-backup --exclude "C:/target/stuff" C:/ D:/backup
```

also with escape characters...

```
rdiff-backup --exclude C:\\/target\\/stuff C:/ D:/backup
```

as well as doing this from the "C:/" directory,

with no luck at all.

Comment: If it is a cygwin program, may be you need `rdiff-backup --exclude /cygdrive/c/target/stuff /cygdrive/c cygdrive/d/backup `

Comment: Good suggestion. After a significant amount of "bit monkeying" around, I've gotten the following to work,      rdiff-backup --exclude O:/DCRC/BOLTS/SHELF_SURVEY_BOLTS_GIS O:/DCRC/BOLTS D:/SharedDrive_backup/BOLTS      According to documentation for running rdiff-backup on WinOS, this should not work but it does. I suspect the problem when I first tried this was a wrong ASCI character.